# apr_memcache_add_server error when trying to restart http

Tags: apache, svn, mod-dav-svn

I am trying to configure svn in my httpd.conf file, my svn version is 1.6.11 and I installed the mod_dav_svn module that was missing with yum install mod_dav_svn(the module is version 1.6.11 too). in the httpd.conf I loaded the module like this:

LoadModule dav_svn_module /opt/csvn/lib/modules/mod_dav_svn.so

and I configure the svn this way:

```
<Location /svn>
 DAV svn
 SVNPath /opt/csvn/data/repositories
 AuthName "Subversion repository"
 AuthType Basic
 AuthUserFile /opt/csvn/data/conf/svn_auth_file
 Require valid-user
</Location>
```

but when I try to restart the apache it gives me an error that says: Cannot load mod_dav_svn.so into server: /opt/csvn/lib/modules/../../lib/libsvn_subr-1.so.0: undefined symbol: apr_memcache_add_server.

one thing that caught my attention is that there are two different paths with two different httpd.conf files, one in /opt/csvn/lib/modules/mod_dav_svn.so and the other one in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. Could this have something to do with the error? Or do I have to upgrade the mod_dav_svn? If this is the case how can I perform the upgrade of the module?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a mix-up of different svn dependencies causing some incompatibility problem. Check the APR version.

Note that you must use up-to-date Subversion version. Today it is SVN 1.9 with 1.9.6 being the latest patch update. There is no practical reason to use outdated SVN 1.6 now. Version 1.6 is not supported for more than four years. What is more 1.6.11 is not even the last patch update which is 1.6.23.